# Spring SpEL can't use space character when parsing List with @Value annotation

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to parse a List of Lists of Strings using SPeL. **Param is specified using command line argument but not .properties file.** Everything works fine when I don't use a space character inside String literal, but when I do then I get a parse exception.

EDIT: I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE

List with `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("#{${param}}")
private List<List<String>> param;
```

Properties specified as command line argument, which doesn't work:

```
--param={{'With Space','b'},{'x','y'}}
```

Results in exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ParseException: Expression [#{{{'With}] @4: Found non terminating string literal starting at position 4
```

This does work:

```
--param={{'WithoutSpace','b'},{'x','y'}}
```

Is there a way to parse such a List with a String element(s) that contains a space character?

Comment: What version of Spring? I just copied/pasted your code/param and it works fine with Spring 5.2.9. `[[With Space, b], [x, y]]`.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE

Comment: I just changed my app to use 2.2.9 instead of 2.3.4; 2.2.9 uses spring-expression 5.2.8 and it still works fine for me; perhaps you can post a complete (small) app that exhibits this behavior so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: I see what's wrong, it seems it only happens when you specify it using command line argument `--param={{'With Space','b'},{'x','y'}}` , but it does work fine when you specify it in .properties file. Just updated this question.

Answer (score 2):

The command line argument should be:

```
--param="{{'With Space','b'},{'x','y'}}"
```

to be properly parsed! Notice the quote character `"` around the --param value after `=` and at the end.